# What does [L] mean in apache rewrite?

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Like here:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.[\d]+\.(css|js)$ $1.$2 [L]
```

Comment: Where did you look first?  What documentation did you check?  I'm curious as to what search you tried that came up empty.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`[L]` is a flag that means that if this rule matches, then no other rule matching will be performed for this page.

The [mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/rewrite_flags.html#flag_l) says:

> The [L] flag causes mod_rewrite to stop processing the rule set. In most contexts, this means that if the rule matches, no further rules will be processed.

However, the documentation goes on to note that `[L]` should not be relied on on its own to stop mod_rewrite processing as if, for example, your rule causes an HTTP redirect then it's possible to re-encounter the ruleset again, which can result in infinte loops.

> It is therefore important, if you are using RewriteRule directives in one of these context that you take explicit steps to avoid rules looping, and not count solely on the [L] flag to terminate execution of a series of rules

Answer (score 1):

If the rule matches, no more will be processed.

Check out the full list of flags: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/rewrite_flags.html

Answer (score 1):

It means that if this rule matches, no more rule matching should be done. L = Last.

[Documentation for l/last](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/rewrite_flags.html#flag_l).

Answer (score 1):

> The [L] flag causes mod_rewrite to
>   stop processing the rule set. In most
>   contexts, this means that if the rule
>   matches, no further rules will be
>   processed.

From [the Apache mod_rewrite Flags documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/rewrite%5Fflags.html#flag_l).

Answer (score 0):

it means last, the rewrite engine will stop searching for matching rules. You can consult the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/rewrite_flags.html#flags).

Usually it's use to avoid to match other rule, you can use it when you are sure you don't need to do any other rewriting.